# Which of design patterns are much suitable to control a sequence of operations

Tags: design-patterns

Assume there are several operations for 1: "Unzipping a a zip file", 2: "Setting some configurations" and 3: "Running the .exe file". Therefore there a a sequence of operations that should be execute one after another. I found out that one of the good pattern to do this, is "Command Pattern" but i scruple about it. Is there another patterns that may be more suitable doing this?

Comment: You don't need pattern for this. Patterns are usually good to use for frameworks. For example, Factory is good when you creating hundreds of controls that do something in your application. Why would you need a pattern if you only going to have 2-3 controls? You really need to find a balance, when to use pattern and when to just code what you need. If you feel that your application could grow to do something else in the future then you may need to look for patterns.

Comment: Thanks, but patterns are not for frameworks. Patterns are a bunch of the best solutions for some common programming problems. Factory is not just for handling controls but it is a way for handling a diversity of unknown future type,on the other hand, you use factory pattern to be able not to depend on a Type (The variety of databases , For example).I do not agree with you in this opinion but thank you.

Comment: :o)You just said it yourself - "...a way for handling a diversity of unknown future type..." What if you don't have "future types". I've written serious systems with many patterns implemented. And I also have written tools, where, basically, I have something "quick and dirty". Right now I need a tool that needs to find all types marked with some attribute and build a list of key/value pairs, and output it to notepad. Why would I spend time for patterns? I just need an app.If I see future reusability, I would do it by Strategy pattern, for example, so I could read different types of attributes

Comment: Something I just came across: "[pattern] provides guidance on how to manage heaps of views and, quite obviously, comes at a cost: the cost of increased complexity in the application code. As you can imagine, these costs are easier to absorb in large applications than in simple programs. Therefore, is not just for any application ..." - basically this supports my view. It is written by Microsoft MVP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually follow a template pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern.
You can implement the same by creating a class say Job and having a main method called execute.
This execute method intern calls three template methods each for your mentioned operation in a desired sequence.

This a flexible pattern, In a sense if later you would like to customize the configuration setup for one situation without affecting anything else, you can create a subclass of Job and just override one of the three template methods for setting up configuration, and it will work. Notice that there would be no changed required for main execute method, since the flow still remains the same.

Template method is often followed while designing frameworks, that allows users to override small functionality without tempering the whole work flow of the framework.